# undefined variable, but variable is defined/declared

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo data out of a database, however, i am getting the following errors, even though all 3 variables have been.

> Notice: Undefined variable: fran_phone in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PhpProject2/testing.php on line 58

For the following:

- Fran_phone
- Twit
- Fb

**Code**

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
$dbc = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "One_Delivery");
$dbc->set_charset("utf8mb4");
if (isset($_GET['area'])) {

    $franc_details = $_GET['area'];
    $get_franc_dets = "SELECT * FROM Franc_dets WHERE Fran_City = '$franc_details'";
    $run_get_franc_dets = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_franc_dets);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($run_get_franc_dets);


    while ($row_get_franc_dets = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_franc_dets)) {

        $franc_phone = $row_get_franc_dets['Fran_Contact_Num'];
        $twit = $row_get_franc_dets['Twitter'];
        $fb = $row_get_franc_dets['Fb'];
    }
}
?>

<div id='franc_div' >

    <table id='franchise_dets'>

        <tr id='frnc_tbl'>
            <td class='collapse'>
                <img src='./Images/franc_dets_phone.png'  height='50' width='50' alt='Call us'>    
            </td>

            <td class='phn_dets'>
                <p id='phn_title'>Problems ordering?</p>
                <p id='phn_numb'><?php echo $franc_phone ?></p>
            </td>

            <td class='collapse'>
                <img src='./Images/franc_dets_twitter.png'  height='50' width='50' alt='Twitter logo'>    
            </td>


            <td class='twitter_dets'>
                <p id='sm_title'>Social media</p>
                <a id='sm_twit' href='https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twit ?>'>@<?php echo $twit ?></a>
            </td>

            <td class='collapse'>
                <img src='./Images/franc_dets_fb.png'  height='50' width='50' alt='Facebook logo' >    
            </td>


            <td class='fb_dets'>

                <a id='sm_fb' href='https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb; ?>'><?php echo $fb; ?></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

where did i go wrong? what can i do to resolve it

Comment: I don't see a `fran_phone` in your code. I see `$franc_phone`, but `fran`!=`franc`

Comment: @Sean sorry you lost me. yes  $franc_phone

Comment: You are only declaring those variables `if (isset($_GET['area'])) {` so the first time into the page when the user has not yet entered anything they will of course be UNDEFINED

Comment: @RiggsFolly i should have explained better, the url is .... area=Enfield

Comment: @Monroe yes, but if no rows are returned then the variables still aren't declared. Did you even care reading my answer which actually mentioned that?

Comment: @Vallentin i did indeed read your answer, i have already tried something along them lines, which did not work for me either

Comment: @Monroe my answer solves the problem stated in the question, so if it still doesn't work then there's clearly something else wrong as well.

Comment: @Vallentin i am a newbie, so i just want to make sure, i understand 100%. after the num_row am i right to say this is where i would then insert while(......

Comment: @Monroe yes you are correct, that was also what I meant with the "Do what you were already doing" comment.

Comment: @Vallentin was just double checking, to ensure i did not do anything wrong to warrant your code not to work

Answer (score 1):

So there's 2 things wrong.

You're clearly trying to learn/switch to prepared statements.
[`mysqli_stmt_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) requires a statement, but you're giving it an [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object.

Instead of using [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) you need to use [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Franc_dets WHERE Fran_City = ?;";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $franc_details);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    // Check how many if any rows were returned.
    $num_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    // Do what you were already doing,
    // and loop through each returned row.
}
```

Note that if 0 rows are returned, then you would get the same error(s). As then the variables won't be defined.