# Notice: Undefined variable... variables declared error

Tags: php, html

i recently posted but i do not think i explained it to well.

I have a page products page the url is for example http:.......rest_id=3/area='Enfield'. I have been using similar query throughout my website but this one is not working, even though it was working for about 2 minutes earlier.

I am using a GET statement to get the area name which is in the url, then from there i use the area name to get the correct data from the DB, such as phone number, twitter and Facebook handles. but nothing is showing.

I have error handlers, the only error i have is Notice: Undefined variable: twit in... For all 3 variables, even though they have been declared.

Any ideas why this may be happening.

```
  if (isset($_GET['area'])) {
                    $franc_dets = $_GET['area'];
                    $get_franc_d = "SELECT * FROM Franc_dets WHERE Fran_City = '$franc_dets'";
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($run_get_franc_d);
                    $iii = 1;

                    while ($row_get_fram = mysqli_fetch_array($run_get_franc_d)) {
                        $fran_phone = $row_get_fram['Fran_Contact_Num'];
                        $twit = $row_get_fram['Twitter'];
                        $iii++;
```

HTML

```
   ......
    <td class='phn_dets'>
                        <p id='phn_title'>Problems ordering?</p>
                        <p id='phn_numb'><?php echo $fran_phone ?></p>
                    </td> 
                    <td class='collapse'>
                        <img src='./Images/franc_dets_twitter.png'  height='50' width='50' alt='Twitter logo'>    
                    </td>


                    <td class='twitter_dets'>
                        <p id='sm_title'>Social media</p>
                        <a id='sm_twit' href='https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twit ?>'>@<?php echo $twit ?></a>
                    </td>

                     <td class='collapse'>
                     <img src='./Images/franc_dets_fb.png'  height='50' width='50' alt='Facebook logo' >    
                    </td>
                    <td class='fb_dets'>

                <a id='sm_fb' href='https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb; ?>'><?php echo $fb; ?></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`?

Comment: @evsar3 yes i have, unfortunately the result is no different

Comment: What happened when you used `var_dump($twit);` inside the while loop?

Comment: instead of creating a new question, that is just as vague as the 1st, you should just update the original question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094876/undefined-variable-but-variable-is-defined-declared

Comment: @enhzflep nothing changes, prints the same notice

Comment: @Monroe - I seem to have made a mistake. The variable I was actually interested in was `$row_get_fram`. What does `var_dump($row_get_fram);` print?

Comment: @enhzflep absolutely nothing, i am so confused and frustrated right about now

Comment: @Monroe - absolutely nothing, as in no output, or absolutely nothing as in one of these two: `array(0) { }` or `NULL`? It sounds like your query is perhaps returning an empty set, as mentioned by Pier. What I've done in the past is var_dump everything that goes into constructing the query and then manually write the sql that I _think_ the code should be constructing from that. On more than one occasion this has helped me realize I'd made a mistake somewhere. I use PDO instead of mysqli - I do note that [continued]

Comment: A quick google of `mysqli_stmt_execute` shows that it is used to execute a _previously prepared statement_ - you're not using one of them. You're merely constructing a string, they're different. This page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php tells you that the input to the function _is not_ a string, but rather - it's the result of a previous call to `mysqli_prepare`. I'd be very surprised if this isn't the sticking point. ;) Have a look at the example given in this man page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 3):

You declare $twit within the while loop. If your query returns no results, then $twit is never defined, therefore the notice you see. In your case I see 2 reasons why you would get no results even if there is data in your DB:

1. There is quotes in your URL and in your queries, which can conflicts and make the query fail.
2. You put your query in mysqli_stmt_execute() which expect a Mysqli Statement, not a string. You have to pass your query in mysqli_prepare(). Then put the result in mysqli_stmt_execute()

Make sure to handle properly the case where no results are returned, which can be as simple that giving a default value to $twit outside the while loop or tell the user that there is no results.

Also, the way you put the variable in your query makes your website vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I suggest you read on the subject. Use prepared queries with placeholders. See the examples in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)